# Apply a superclass method on several instances with polymorphism by using pointers in C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a superclass Athlete which provides a virtual void work() method, which is redefined in subclass Climber. I would like to create a big number of instances from the classes Athlete and Climber and apply to them the work() method, in just a couple of lines, thanks to polymorphism. I know, thanks to my searches, that it is possible with pointers, but I don't know how...

I know how to use pointers in order to apply the work() method on these instances, but only if I do that one by one like that:

```cpp
class Athlete {
          .....
     virtual void work {
          cout << getName() << " is training very hard." << endl;
    }
};

class Climber: public Athlete{
      ......
    void work(){
        cout << getName() << " is climbing very hard." << endl;
    }
    .....
};


    Athlete athlete1 = Athlete(...);
    Climber climber1 = Climber(...);
            ....

    Athlete* a1 = &athlete1;
    Athlete* a2 = &climber1;
            ....

    a1->work();
    a2->work();     
            ....
```

But I don't know how to use a for-loop to automatically do that for thousands of instances for example. Can someone help me to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a *vector* to store the pointers to all your objects,

Comment: You can have a vector of pointers.

Comment: How would you do it if they were all the same class?

Comment: This is a fairly basic, fundamental C++ topic. Unfortunately a search engine is not a replacement for a textbook, neither is Stackoverflow. Only a textbook will be able to explained, in an organized, methodical way, of various approaches of storing and managing polymorphic objects, like vectors and arrays, explain common pitfalls like object slicing, and various alternatives that handle that, ranging from plain pointers to smart pointers. Do you have a textbook that you can refer to, on these topics?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a textbook on C++. I learned C++ only on internet, and especially on youtube...

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested in a concrete solution and come on this page, here is one.

Thanks to the comments under my question, I was able to improve my searches on this topic and found a solution. I don't know if it is the perfect solution for my problem but at least, it works.

Here is the solution:

```
...

#include <vector>
....

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

// Create a vector of pointers:
    vector<Athlete*> team;

// Call constructors to create instances:
    Athlete athlete1 = Athlete(...);
    Climber climber1 = Climber(...);
    Athlete athlete2 = Athlete(...);
    Climber climber2 = Climber(...);

// Fill the vector with pointers on instances:
    team = {&athlete1,&athlete2,&climber1,&climber2};

// Apply the work method() on every instances:
    for (Athlete * &i : team) 
    {
        i->work();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe someone can give me some improvement suggestions, and probably about the filling of the "team" vector, or about anything else.